# Are BrainF*ck tape spots overflowing?

Tags: integer-overflow, brainfuck

Can I assume that if you do `-` on a tape spot with 0, that it loops around to 255?
Otherwise I don't understand how you can start a loop with `-` without first incrementing?

e.g:

```
+[----->+++<]>+.+.[--->+<]>---.+[----->+<]>.++.--.
```

Comment: Another source: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Conventions